# CSS not aligning text inside the Div

Tags: html, css

I am getting a line break on space. I don't why it is happening

Please check below code

```
<div id="postcode_phone">
  <div id="sub_area_text1">02036MMM4</div>
  <div id="sub_area_textgmt">GMT +1</div>
  <div id="sub_area_texttime">Mon-Fri 8:00am - 5:00pm<br>Sat: 8:00am - 1:00pm </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#postcode_phone{
  position:relative;
  background:url(images/phonebanner.png) no-repeat;
  width:222px;
  height:81px;
}

#sub_area_text1 {
  font-size:1.2em;
  font-family: 'Corbol';
  color:#31ACFF;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-left:30px;
}

#sub_area_textgmt {
  font-size:0.8em;
  font-family: 'Corbol';
  color:#999999;
  text-align:right;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-right:60px;
  width:10px;
  border:5px solid gray;
  margin:0px;
  float:left;
}

#sub_area_texttime {
  font-size:0.8em;
  font-family: 'Corbol';
  color:#999999;
  text-align:center;
  padding-right:90px;
  width:40px;
  border:5px solid gray;
  margin:0px;
  float:right;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d5Z6V/31/

Comment: where is the line break? On the date/time info?

Comment: Just wondering: Any reason for the width limitation plus massive padding on the `#sub_area_texttime` and `#sub_area_textgmt` divs?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d5Z6V/34/

Comment: @Franck i want "GMT +1" text alignment on the right side of the div

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d5Z6V/35/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `white-space:nowrap;` in your `#sub_area_texttime`.

Comment: Don't forget to increase the `with` of `sub_area_texttime` too.

Comment: In other implementations this would cause the width of a container to be changed and can cause formatting issues.  Changing the width and padding is a more sound answer.

Answer (score 1):

You gave the sub_area_texttime div a width of 40px and a padding-right of 90px.  Increase width or decrease the padding. It's wrapping the line because the container is too small.

Comment: this is the correct way. don't forget to add the `padding` you remove back to the `width` http://jsfiddle.net/cg3ST/1/

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP i got text-align:right; in sub_area_textgmt but it is not aligning to right you can check in jsfiddle

Comment: It's not aligning right because you need to lower the padding and or increase the width.  Make the padding 10px and the width 180px and you'll see it working.